# Data missing in mongo find() query response

Tags: mongodb-query, response, missing-data

I'm using mongo's `find()` query to retrieve users from MongoDB but there are some users missing in the API response. Although, they are there in the DB if I manually search them using Mongo Compass.

This is so strange, never happened to me before!

Any help would be highly appreciated.